# Possible to add an overlay on a map using MapKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

Is it possible to add an overlay image on top of a map added in my app? I am using MapKit to show the map of an area. I would like to add an overlay image on top of the map before the pins show up

i.e. the stack should be **map->image overlay->pins**

Is it possible without going into the hierarchy of views - get all subviews of the view and then add an image just on top of the map?

Thanks.

Comment: does the overlay have to move along with the underlying map?

Comment: no, neither does the map actually.. Its just that with a map, it would be easier for me to put in pins for POIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you need a solution for a static map , but here's one for a "draggable" one , which should also solve your problem.

You should subclass `MKOverlayView` , and override its (empty by default):

`- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context`.

The method should actually do what `drawRect` does in views.
You should also implement another "should" method , that should return TRUE if the overlay should be visible on screen (in your case.. always ?).

In the overriden method , you should draw your image on top of the map (according to the mapRect and zoomScale of course) , and viola!

Some more reference :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look into the `MKOverlayView` outlined in the `MKMapView` documentation (see [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)). In addition, it may be worth reviewing "Apple WWDC Session 127 - Customizing Maps with Overlays".

Comment: This adds a region on the map along with a pin. I want to add an image on top of the map. Pins will be added on top of the image. Essentially I want to add an image between the pins and the map.

Comment: The image will be a static image.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch that "Apple WWDC Session 127 - Customizing Maps with Overlays" session there is a part about about raster images as overlays.  If you download the 2010 WWDC Sample Code there is an example named "TileMap" which has the code for doing that.